# Read request to PHP as a stream

Tags: php, stream

Is it possible to read the request body sent to PHP as a stream, so i do not need to wait for the entire request body to arrive, before starting to do work?

Basically I need to read the data sent to a webserver (via POST) before it arrives and get parsed into $_POST. It this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), to get data before parsing.

Comment: Same answer as to @Pez above